# Getting error "'encypt' is not a valid command" while trying to encrypt using Spring boot CLI

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am trying to encrypt a password using Spring boot CLI (1.5.7).

```
./spring encrypt mysecret --key ashish
```

I am getting below error for this command:

```
'encypt' is not a valid command. See 'help'.
```

Please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

Actually encrypt and decrypt comes with Spring Cloud CLI
so below command will get you these commands

```
./spring install org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:1.3.2.RELEASE
```

But now I am getting different error
"Unable to initialize due to invalid secret key"

Anyone any ideas ?

Comment: If you still have a question, don't provide it as an answer just modify the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in the `Spring Boot CLI` documentation:

> Prerequisites: to use the encryption and decryption features you need
> the full-strength JCE installed in your JVM (it’s not there by
> default). You can download the "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE)
> Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files" from Oracle, and follow
> instructions for installation (essentially replace the 2 policy files
> in the JRE lib/security directory with the ones that you downloaded).