# Installing sprinboot cloud failing

Tags: spring, macos, spring-boot

I'm trying to install springboot cloud but i'm getting this error dnt know how to solve it. I managed to install spring successful

```
spring --version
Spring CLI v2.1.6.RELEASE

spring install org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
Installing into: /usr/local/Cellar/springboot/2.1.6.RELEASE/lib/ext
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/springboot/2.1.6.RELEASE/lib/spring-boot-cli-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/groovy-2.5.7.jar!/) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

And after when i'm running this command

```
spring encrypt mysecret --key foo    


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.cli.command.encrypt.BaseEncryptOptionHandler.option(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljoptsimple/OptionSpecBuilder;
    at org.springframework.cloud.cli.command.encrypt.BaseEncryptOptionHandler.options(BaseEncryptOptionHandler.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.options.OptionHandler.getParser(OptionHandler.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.options.OptionHandler.run(OptionHandler.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.OptionParsingCommand.run(OptionParsingCommand.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:218)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.runAndHandleErrors(CommandRunner.java:170)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.SpringCli.main(SpringCli.java:63)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: I can't see any error. It has just `WARNING`s

Comment: the problem is when i run this command  ``` spring encrypt mysecret --key foo                                             
'encrypt' is not a valid command. See 'help'.  ```

Comment: can you look into this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626320/getting-error-encypt-is-not-a-valid-command-while-trying-to-encrypt-using-sp

Comment: i'm now getting the above exception

Comment: @Shahzeb thanks. it working now
spring encrypt mysecret --key foo                                                   
ac2986772fc1e5909cf644fc8947bf50be143b13dc26929e1f1ad52e701055d6

Comment: No problem. Share all your steps by answering your question. Might be helpful for someone else in future.

Comment: brew tap pivotal/tap
brew install springboot
I just had to install the version 2.1.0
spring install org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT